# mysql prepare statement to insert data in table

Tags: java, mysql

mysql prepare statement to insert data in table
where table have 3 fields(id,name,branch)
where id is PK ann Auto incremented

mycode

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("insert into student_tbl values(?,?)");

st.setString(2, "Ram");
st.setString(3, "TX");
int i = st.executeUpdate();
```

what wil be the code to insert only 2 n 3 value

Comment: specify column names like insert into `student_tbl(name,branch)`

Answer (score 3):

You should just define your column names and exclude the `id` like this:

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO student_tbl (name, branch) values(?,?)");

st.setString(1, "Ram");
st.setString(2, "TX");
int i = st.executeUpdate();
```